# How is the subset $U = \{\alpha({\bf i} +2{\bf j} + 3{\bf k}) \mid \alpha \in \Bbb R\}$ a subspace of $V = \Bbb R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

So, I'm kind of stumped on this question. It probably is trivial, but I'm new to Linear Algebra. 
The question is to show that the subset $U = \{\alpha({\bf i} +2{\bf j} + 3{\bf k}) \mid \alpha \in \Bbb R\}$ is a subspace of  $V = \Bbb R^3$ or disprove it with a counterexample.

My attempt:

Let $a,b\in\Bbb R$, since $\alpha \in \Bbb R$,

- replacing $\alpha$ with $a$,
- let vector ${\bf v} = a({\bf i} +2{\bf j} + 3{\bf k})$
- let vector ${\bf u} = b({\bf i} + 2{\bf j} + 3{\bf k})$

which are both in this subset since, again, $\alpha$ can be any real number.

Since, any two vectors in a set have to closed under addition for this set to be a subspace,
$${\bf v}+{\bf u} = (a+b){\bf i} + 2(a+b){\bf j} + 3(a+b){\bf k} = (a+b)({\bf i} + 2{\bf j} + 3{\bf k}),$$
where $a+b$ is the addition of any two real numbers which are obviously in $\Bbb R$, and since the condition is $\alpha \in \Bbb R$, this subset is, in fact, a subspace.

BUT, my mind keeps telling me it isn't.

Cheers (:

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This is perfectly fine, although you also need to verify that the set is closed under multiplication by scalars (which it is).  So the real question seems to be, why does your mind think it isn't a subspace?  What about it doesn't seem subspace-like?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! @GNUSupporter

Comment: @ErickWong I'm not sure how to show that (a + b) is a valid alpha. I mean, intuitively, I see it, but I just can't seem to prove it explicitly.

Comment: @Anjani Addition is well-defined on real numbers.  If $a$ and $b$ are real then so is $a+b$.  Any real number is a valid alpha.  But that's not what you said at the bottom of your question: you said your mind tells you it isn't a subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that a nonempty subset $U$ of $V$ is a subspace of $V$, one needs

- $\forall u,v \in U,u+v\in U$
- $\forall u\in U, \forall \lambda \in F, \lambda u \in U$, where $F$ is a field.  (In linear algebra courses, $F$ is often $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$.  $F$ is $\Bbb R$ in the case.)

You've proved the first point, and for a *proof*, the second point is needed.  It's trivial from the expression of $\bf u$ in terms of $a$, $\bf i$, $\bf j$ and $\bf k$ though.

To simplify the writing (which is useful especially in tests/exams), il suffices to say

- $\forall u,v \in U, \forall \lambda \in F, \lambda u+v \in U$

---

Let ${\bf v}, {\bf u} \in U$, $\lambda \in \Bbb R$.  $\exists a,b \in \Bbb R$ such that ${\bf v} = a({\bf i} +2{\bf j} + 3{\bf k})$ and ${\bf u} = b({\bf i} + 2{\bf j} + 3{\bf k})$.  Add them to finish the proof.

$${\bf v}+\lambda {\bf u} = (a+\lambda b){\bf i} + 2(a+\lambda b){\bf j} + 3(a+\lambda b){\bf k} = (a+\lambda b)({\bf i} + 2{\bf j} + 3{\bf k}) \in U$$

Comment: To be very general, one also needs to verify two other things that tend to be obvious or straightforward: that $U$ is in fact contained in $V$, and that $U$ is non empty (alternatively, that it contains the zero vector of $V$).  Also that $V$ is a vector space, although this usually is known by the time one asks the question.

Comment: @ErickWong Thanks for pointing them out.  I've edited my post.